# Is the exponential speedup and output $\langle x|M|x\rangle$ in contradiction in HHL algorithm?

Tags: complexity-theory, hhl-algorithm, speedup

Isn't the exponential speedup and the output $\langle x|M|x\rangle$ in contradiction in HHL algorithm? How can we print the solution vector $|x\rangle$ without losing the exponential speedup?

Comment: The beginning of page 2 of the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.3171) provides the answer.  "Clearly, to read out all the components of $\vec x$ would require one to perform the procedure at least $N$ times.  However, often one is interested not in $\vec x$ itself, but in some expectation calue $\vec x^T M\vec x$, where $M$ is some linear operator (our procedure also accommodates nonlinear operators as described below)."